# .NET HotChocolate generic type pagination

Tags: .net, graphql, hotchocolate

with Hot chocolate platform, I created a response type for my lists:
`ListResponseBase(IQueryable<T> Result, ResponseStatus status)`.
Then I want to `UsePaging` for my query: `ListResponseBase<User> GetUsers()`.
but I got error message in schema building step: ListResponseBase should be iterate-able.
I even use `UsePaging<User>()` but I got error: cannot fetch data from source.
how could I resolve this? Am I wrong in my ResponseBase pattern? then how I can return Status in all calls? thanks.

**Edit:**
this is my simple ListResponseBase class:

```
public class ListResponseBase<TResult>
{
    public IQueryable<TResult> Result { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my query:

```
        [GraphQLName("user_getUsers")]
        [UsePaging]
        public ListResponseBase<User> GetUsers([Service] IUserService userService)
        {
            return userService.GetUsers();
        }
```

my service:

```
    public ListResponseBase<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return new ListResponseBase<User> { Status = ResponseStatus.Success, Result = userRepository.GetUsers() };  
    }
```

and finally my repo:

```
        public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return context.Users;
        }
```

Comment: can you post the ListResponseBase<T> class?

Comment: @MichaelIngmarStaib I just edit my post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just fix this issue with add `UsePaging` to my repository and `ListResponseBase<T>` :

```
    public class ListResponseBase<TResult> 
{
    [UseOffsetPaging]
    public IQueryable<TResult> Result { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus Status { get; set; }
}

 public interface IUserRepository
{
    User GetUser(int userId);
    [UseOffsetPaging]
    IQueryable<User> GetUsers();
    User GetUser(string externalId);
}
```